# In ExtJS, how to disable hover over style change on Toolbar button disabled?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a toolbar in ExtJS and I have a button, I am actually disabling the button in some cases if the user doesn't have access. If I disable it, it is disabled and doesn't launch the client event. So that's great.

But hovering over the button still changes the background color of the button indicating to the user that its enabled and its not.

I tried looking into some CSS issues but I couldn't find anything.

How can I to do this? The only thing I am doing on the button Item is:

```
        disabled: !isAdmin
```

and the toolbar is being created like so:

```
   var toolbar = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
        dock: 'top',
        width: 700,
        height: 56,
        items: [
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you added some custom styles for button on hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created Sencha fiddle for the same it works fine. I tried with Extjs 4.2 version also and it don't change background color on hover for disabled button

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14j8

Check overCls for more information

Comment: Thanks, for confirming. It seems i have some custom css attached to it.... hard to track down..